# QML Canvas on Android, Orientation Issue

Tags: android, canvas, orientation, qml, qt-quick

I'm fairly new to QML (on Android) so forgive me if this is a trivial thing. I'm trying to use the Canvas object to draw some custom graphs etc. However I can't get it to behave nicely with changing screen orientation. If I start my app in portrait orientation, it looks ok until I switch to landscape. Same happens if I start it landscape. Everything is ok until I go portrait. How can I fix this behavior? Here's a simple test I'm having trouble with:

```
import QtQuick 2.2
import QtQuick.Window 2.1

Window {
    visible: true
    visibility: Window.FullScreen

    Rectangle {
        anchors.fill: parent
        color: "red"

        Canvas {
            anchors.fill: parent

            onPaint: {
                var ctx = getContext("2d")

                ctx.fillStyle = "blue"
                ctx.fillRect(0, 0, width, height)

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here's what happens. If I start the above app portrait, it fills the screen with both the red background rectangle and the blue canvas on top of it (I can actually see it drawing the both). When I go landscape, this is what I end up with.

[image: Portrait to landscape]

The canvas does not fill the entire screen anymore. It seems to be now a perfect square and clipping the right side off (It's not stretching. You'd see this if there was more content). Similar thing happens if I start landscape and go portrait:

[image]

Comment: You didn't mention what actually goes wrong. We might be able to pinpoint your problem without having access to an Android device if you post a screenshot or describe the issue.

Comment: Sorry. I edited the question and added a couple of illustrations of what's happening.

Comment: Thanks. Which Qt version are you using?

Comment: Qt 5.3 on Android 4.1.2

Comment: a quick check could be adding paint requests on width and height change of the canvas (and also displaying those with a Text element, or logging on change, too)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not actually too sure about my previous answer anymore. Might have been just lucky incidence. I think I found the real reason for this behavior. If I deploy the application so that it uses the Ministro service on my phone, then I'll get this buggy behavior. But if I bundle Qt from my build machine into the package, everything works fine. Tested twice with the same project and same source files... I have Ministro 9.6.8 on my phone and the latest official Qt on my machine.

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question as one of the possible solutions. It looks like the "anchors.fill: parent" lines in my original code do not update the width and height properties in the respective levels by default. The following code seems to gets rid of the problem:

```
import QtQuick 2.2
import QtQuick.Window 2.1

Window {
    id: root
    width: Screen.width
    height: Screen.height
    visible: true
    visibility: Window.FullScreen


    Rectangle {
        anchors.fill: parent
        width: parent.width
        height: parent.height
        color: "red"

        Canvas {
            anchors.fill: parent
            width: parent.width
            height: parent.height

            onPaint: {
                var ctx = getContext("2d")

                ctx.fillStyle = "blue"
                ctx.fillRect(0, 0, width, height)

            }
        }
    }
}
```